# Start Windows 10 sandbox in predefined state with additional software

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-sandbox

Windows 10 has a new [sandbox](https://www.howtogeek.com/399290/how-to-use-windows-10s-new-sandbox-to-safely-test-apps/) which is based on a very small and fast Hyper-V VM. With every start of the sandbox you get a "fresh" Windows and on every sandbox termination, all changes are discarded.

My question is: Is it possible to define in which state the sandbox starts? E.g. is it possible to start the VM with pre-installed reversing tools or a script that is automatically run, as soon as the system is booted?

Use case: Due to it's fast start-up time and "throw away" characteristics, the Windows 10 sandbox would be a dream for automated malware analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can somehow change the behavior of the sandbox. For example run a script at start up or disable network. See here for a how to: https://medium.com/@maarten.goet/how-windows-1903-makes-malware-analysis-easier-introducing-windows-sandbox-3ec791c8367

Comment: I suggest adding some details from that external link to the answer... eventually that link will die and the answer won't be useful anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In general, sandbox startup can be controlled by a startup configuration file:

> Windows Sandbox supports simple configuration files, which provide a
> minimal set of customization parameters for Sandbox. ... Windows Sandbox
> configuration files are formatted as XML and are associated with
> Sandbox via the `.wsb` file extension.

The specific ability to execute a script upon sandbox startup is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-configure-using-wsb-file#logon-command

It says:

> ## Logon command
>
> Specifies a single command that will be invoked automatically after
> the sandbox logs on. Apps in the sandbox are run under the container
> user account. The container user account should be an administrator
> account.
>
> ### XML
>
> ```
> <LogonCommand>
>   <Command>command to be invoked</Command>
> </LogonCommand>
> ```
>
> `Command`: A path to an executable or script inside the container that
> will be executed after signing in.
>
> ### Note
>
> Although very simple commands will work (such as launching an
> executable or script), more complicated scenarios involving multiple
> steps should be placed into a script file. This script file may be
> mapped into the container via a shared folder, and then executed via
> the `LogonCommand` directive.